# haskell libmagic how to use it?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a program that will check the file type of a certain file and I found a haskell [library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/magic-1.0.8) that should do the trick.
The problem arises when I try to use it. I have no idea what I have to do, which function to call etc. The library is full of cryptic commands with no examples, no tutorial or a homepage.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [package's documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/magic/1.0.8/doc/html/Magic.html) that contains short descriptions of the important functions (which are not *that* many). For additional information about what the underlying C library does (and therefore also the Haskell library), have a look at [libmagic's man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic).

The basic usage should look similar to this (untested):

```
import Magic.Init
import Magic.Operations

main =
   do magic <- magicOpen []
      loadDefaultMagic magic
      magicFile magic "/my/file" >>= print
```